# What is the difference between "per", "por", "pri" and "pro"?

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning

What is the difference between *per*, *por*, *pri*, and *pro*?

All these words look and feel sort of similar to me. What are the possible uses for each of them? How do I decide which to use?

Answer (score 17):

> ## “per” denotes who or what helps the sentence happen.

- It can denote an **instrument**:

  - *Bati iun per bastono.*
  - *Trafi du celojn per unu ŝtono.*
  - *Ni vidas per la okuloj kaj aŭdas per la oreloj.*
- It can denote an **intermediary actor**:

  - *Sendi leteron per servisto.*
- It can denote a **body part** serving as a locus for some action:

  - *Teni la hundon per la oreloj.*
- It can denote a more **abstract tool**:

  - *Per helpo de vortaro, mi komprenis vian leteron.*
- It can denote a **manner**:

  - *Ni ne povas atingi ĉiujn celojn per unu fojo.*
  - *Ekkrii per terura voĉo.*
  - *Marŝi per piedoj nudaj.*

> ## “por” denotes a goal, beneficiary, or target.

- Literally:

  - *La preparoj por la venonta kongreso.*
  - *Li riskas por la duba rezultato sian vivon*.
- It can denote a **purpose or target audience**:

  - *Kampo por la eksperimentoj de aeroplanoj.*
  - *Vestoj por infanoj.*
- It can denote both a **purchased object**, and its **price**:

  - *Pagi cent frankojn por sia palto.*
  - *Aĉeti teon por unu franko.*
- With *preni*, it can mean *take something **for** something*:

  - *Mi prenis la danĝeron por ŝerco.*
- It can denote a **concerned party**:

  - *Tio estas granda perdo por ni.*
  - *La kongreso estis vera triumfo por Esperanto.*

> ## “pri” denotes a subject.

- Of a verb:

  - *Elpensi/paroli/dubi/plori pri iu.*
- Of an adjective:

  - *Kontenta/certa/ĝoja/konscia pri io.*
- Of a noun:

  - *La legendo pri Psiĥe.*
  - *Traktato pri paco.*
  - *La demando pri lingvo internacia.*

> ## “pro” denotes a cause.

- Literally:

  - *Mi venis pro serioza afero.*
  - *La maro estis griza pro ŝaŭmo.*
  - *Mi ridas pro lia naiveco.*
- It can also denote a **traded object**.

  - *Kion vi donos pro tio?*
  - *Okulon pro okulo, denton pro dento.*